# How to check what dispatcher is configured in akka application

Tags: multithreading, akka

I have following entry in conf file. But I'm not sure if this dispatcher  setting is being picked up and what's ultimate parallelism value being used

```
        akka{
      actor{
        default-dispatcher {
              type = Dispatcher
              executor = "fork-join-executor"
              throughput = 3
              fork-join-executor {
                parallelism-min = 40
                parallelism-factor = 10
                parallelism-max = 100
              }
            }
       }
    }
```

I've 8 core machine so I expect **80** parallel threads to be in ready state
 **40min < 80 (8*10 factor) < 100max**. I'd like to see what value is akka using for max parallel thread.
I created 45 child actors and in my logs, I'm printing the thread id [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-xx] and I don't see more than 20 threads running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `ActorSystem` instance you can check the values set in its configuration. This is how you could get your hand on the values you've set in the config file:

```scala
val system = ActorSystem()
val config = system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.actor.default-dispatcher")
config.getString("type")
config.getString("executor")
config.getString("throughput")
config.getInt("fork-join-executor.parallelism-min")
config.getInt("fork-join-executor.parallelism-max")
config.getDouble("fork-join-executor.parallelism-factor")
```

I hope this helps. You can also consult [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html) page for more details on specific configuration settings.

**Update**

I've dug up a bit more in Akka to find out exactly what it uses for your settings. As you might already expect it uses a `ForkJoinPool`. The parallelism used to build it is given by:

```
object ThreadPoolConfig {
  ...
  def scaledPoolSize(floor: Int, multiplier: Double, ceiling: Int): Int =
math.min(math.max((Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors * multiplier).ceil.toInt, floor), ceiling)
  ...
}
```

This function is used at some point to build a `ForkJoinExecutorServiceFactory`:

```scala
new ForkJoinExecutorServiceFactory(
  validate(tf),
  ThreadPoolConfig.scaledPoolSize(
    config.getInt("parallelism-min"),
    config.getDouble("parallelism-factor"),
    config.getInt("parallelism-max")),
  asyncMode)
```

Anyway, this is the parallelism that will be used to create the `ForkJoinPool`, which is actually an instance of [`java.lang.ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Now we have to ask how many thread does this pool use? The short answer is that it will use the whole capacity (80 threads in our case) only if it needs it.

To illustrate this scenario, I've ran a couple of tests with various uses of Thread.sleep inside the actor. What I've found out is that it can use from somewhere around 10 threads (if no sleep call is made) to around the max 80 threads (if I call sleep for 1 second). The tests were made on a machine with 8 cores.

Summing it up, you will need to check the implementation used by Akka to see exactly how that parallelism is used, this is why I looked into `ForkJoinPool`. Other than looking at the config file and then inspecting that particular implementation I don't think you can do unfortunately :(

I hope this clarifies the answer - initially I thought you wanted to see how the actor system's dispatcher is configured.

Comment: Yes, this will give the values which were read from config by akka system. However I'm interested to know if there's a way to know what parallelism did akka dispatcher pick ultimately from 3 fields - min,factor & max.

Comment: I've updated the response after running some tests. Also, @Stefano Bonetti is right - to max-out the parallelism all actors need to work at the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to max-out the parallelism factor, all the actors needs to be processing some messages at the same time. Are you sure this is the case in your application?

Take for example the following code

```
object Test extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem()

  (1 to 80).foreach{ _ =>
    val ref = system.actorOf(Props[Sleeper])
    ref ! "hello"
  }
}

class Sleeper extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case msg =>
      //Thread.sleep(60000)
      println(msg)
  }
}
```

If you consider your config and 8 cores, you will see a small amount of threads being spawned (4, 5?) as the processing of the messages is too quick for some real parallelism to build up.

On the contrary, if you keep your actors CPU-busy uncommenting the nasty `Thread.sleep` you will see the number of threads will bump up to 80. However, this will only last 1 minute, after which the threads will be gradually be retired from the pool.

I guess the main trick is: don't think of each actor being run on a separate thread. It's whenever one or more messages appear on an actor's mailbox that the dispatcher awakes and - indeed - dispatches the message processing task to a designated pool.

Comment: I have quite similar code. I'm spawning 45 actors in a for loop. As per my logs it takes about 1 to 1.5sec for computation done in  child actor. I was hoping there'll be a thread dispatched to each child actor in parallel.I guess this is not happening. Any way to enforce it ?

Comment: There is no way to enforce 45 threads being spawned if there are not enough tasks for them. Chances are, in your case there are not. Without seeing your code it's hard to say.